# Get list of MySQL databases, and server version?

Tags: sql, mysql

My connection string for MySQL is:

```
"Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=123;pooling=yes;charset=utf8;DataBase=.;"
```

My questions are :

1. What query should I write to get database names that exist?
2. What query should I write to get server version?
3. I have error because of my connection string ends with `DataBase=.`
   What  should I write instead of the dot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`
2. `SELECT VARIABLE_NAME, VARIABLE_VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'VERSION'`
3. Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as the database.

Answer (score 8):

To get the list of databases, you can use `SHOW DATABASES`:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| test               |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

To get the version number of your MySQL Server, you can use `SELECT VERSION()`:

```
SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.1.45    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

As for the question about the connection string, you'd want to put a database name instead of the dot, such as `Database=test`.

Answer (score 0):

```
show Databases;
```

Will return you all the registered databases.

And

```
show variables;
```

will return a bunch of name value pairs, one of which is the version number.